# Setting Spinner makes checkbox text vertical

Tags: android, text, android-spinner, android-checkbox, vertical-text

I have a table layout in which i have two row. One row has a spinner and the other row has a checkbox as soon as set my spinner some value from dropdown the text of checkbox turn vertical .I tired all my tricks but can't find the solution or a reason this happen only at setting spinner runtime.

Anyone have faced this issue or have any idea about it would be a great help.

Thanks

**Code**

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#dedede"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opPrem_txtName"
        style="@style/iTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/opSpinner_salution"
        style="@style/iET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:entries="@array/Salutation" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/opPrem_editName"
        style="@style/iET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.56"
        android:inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/iTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="DOB " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pr_dobBtn"
        style="@style/iET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opPrem_txtAge"
        style="@style/iTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Age" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/opPrem_editAge"
        style="@style/iET"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.19"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/getContactReMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/getcontact" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/saveContactReMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/addcontact" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: My code .... it doesnot contain complete layout just a table layout creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this on my own. Just use android:stretchColumns="1,2" in table row containing the checkBoxlayout.

The number 1 and 2 indicates the value of view getting wrapped.

ex In my case the checkbox is the third view component of table row so used android:stretchColumns="2" this solved my prob :)